# WordPress admin dashboard missing icons

Tags: php, apache

When I log into the wp-admin dashboard all the icons are missing. Most of them are replaced with a empty square or just a blank spot.

Background:

I've duplicated my WordPress website on two servers - beta and live. On live everything works fine. On beta when I log into the wp-admin dashboard all the icons are missing. To test further I setup a local version of the site on my laptop. The icons appear as normal here.

On my beta server I checked directory permissions, made sure the DB was the same as the live DB ( used a live DB dump ), checked the logs, and also deactivated all plugins. The icons are always missing and there are no obvious or useful error messages being throw.

Update:
The only thing that seems to fix it is this.
If I enable SCRIPT_DEBUG in the config ( to not use minified JS ) - it seems to work.

Picture of dashboard missing icons https://i.stack.imgur.com/LYQEB.jpg

Picture of dashboard with working icons https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6oZc.jpg

Comment: This is the browser console when using minified scripts.  https://ibb.co/WgZnBx8